# UITextField and UILabel in UIScrollVew

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In my iphone app, I need to create a controller for which the view would have the following specs.

- A UITextField at the top of the view
- some UILabel below the UITextField and each UILabel below the previous one
- When entering something in the UITextField, a new UILabel will be added below the last one

(This is pretty much what is done in the Wunderlist iphone app).

To do so, I was thinking of using a UIScrollView instead of the UIView of the controller and add the UITextField and all the UILabel with the [self addSubView:label_i]

Is this approach correct ? At the beginning I tried the UITableView approach but I am not very satisfied with that.

Comment: i've never tried Wunderlist, but it looks like it's using a UITableView. UITableViews are very flexible - might be worth another look?

Comment: @mike-k Totally agree on the flexibility of UITableView. The thing is, when a new item is created (from the UITextField), I'd like the new UILabel (and only that one) to appear with a little effect (fade or stuff). Do you know if only a given cell can appear without refreshing all the others ?

Comment: @Luc iOS provides some built in animations when adding new rows (see "- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation"). otherwise you can do your custom anim in "– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")

Comment: @mike-k rhanks for your help. I'll dig deeper in UITableView then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/) app, this can be implemented using a UITableView with a subclassed, custom UITableViewCell (with transparent margins of `[UIColor clearColor]`).

Here are some helpful links:
["Creating a Custom UITableViewCell In iOS 4"](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/)
["Custom UITableViewCell Using IB"](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

If you want to work with a list of "UILabels," a UITableView will be the best bet by far.

EDIT: The UITextView at the top of the view corresponds to the `tableHeaderView` property.